# Docker failing to add repository Universe

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, debian, debian-stretch

I'm trying to add `universe` as a repository in my docker image:

```
RUN add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"

RUN apt-get update
```

it errors with this output:

```
Step 4/24 : RUN add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
 ---> Running in 4c924d1455ed
Removing intermediate container 4c924d1455ed
 ---> b472a493f90c
Step 5/24 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in d4e292c43bad
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch Release
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe all Packages
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/stretch/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

My Docker file uses `FROM python:2.7-slim` as a base.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Results of `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/os-release`?

Comment: Sorry, how do I get that if the build fails? Is there a RUN command that would print that?

Comment: Yes add a `RUN` statement before `apt update`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I updated my post with the result

Comment: That base image is a Debian image and you are trying to treat it as a ubuntu image. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113590/how-to-add-debian-universe-in-etc-apt-sources-list

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `debian` as base OS image, then you cannot add `ubuntu`'s repository as mentioned by [Tarun Lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66877080/docker-failing-to-add-repository-universe#comment118217131_66877080) in comments.